# Can't insert value into form with javascript

Tags: javascript

this works with no problem:

```
document.getElementById("PvpnetAccountName").value = "Username";
```

this does not work, it does not insert my value into the form:

```
document.getElementById("PvpnetAccountDateOfBirthDay").value = "6";
```

whats wrong? Sitename: https://signup.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/signup or: http://pastebin.com/raw/ZX9JmyDD

Comment: Do you have an element with id `PvpnetAccountDateOfBirthDay`?

Comment: Show the relevant HTML

Comment: relevant HTML: http://pastebin.com/raw/ZX9JmyDD

Comment: It's because you're trying to set the value of a `<select>` element. You'll need to set the selections value, and not the select element.

Comment: And once you fixed it: have fun with the captcha... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code of the website:

```
<select name="data[PvpnetAccount][date_of_birth_day]" id="PvpnetAccountDateOfBirthDay" class="ignore_keyup c-signup__input c-signup__input--select c-form-group__input c-form-group__input--select js-selectize selectized" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
</select>
```

The input field you try access with Javascript actually is a hidden one. It does not contain the option you want to select.
The selection itself is made in the `div` with class `selectize-dropdown-content`. This often is done for styling purpose.

Answer (score -2):

try value to convert int like this:

```
parseInt(value)
```